# Compiling MuPdf for Go Lang Under Linux

Tags: linux, go, mupdf

If there a way to compile **mupdf** library in order to use as go wrapper for converting pdf to images

Compilation can be done under Linux system

Answer (score 1):

mupdf is written in C, so you need to create or use some Go bindings to it.

Searching on https://pkg.go.dev/search?q=mupdf, there are a number of Go packages that expose the functionality of the mupdf libraries.

The most popular one of these libraries seems to be https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gen2brain/go-fitz, which provides a way to extract pages from a PDF document. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: i had used couple of libraries, but what if i want to build a custom one by myself?

Comment: https://github.com/gen2brain/go-fitz/blob/master/fitz.go has a bit of C code in a comment near the top, followed by `import "C"`. That's how cgo creates code for calling into C. See https://blog.golang.org/cgo for more on cgo.